# Trying to refactor even better

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, refactoring, android-volley

I have refactored `checkLogin()` which lives in the `LoginActivity` class, but I still think that it can be refactored even better.

```
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.getUrlLogin(), ReqSuccessListener(), ReqErrorListener()) {

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(loginRequest, tag_string_req);
}
```

The implementation of `ReqSuccessListener()` and `ReqErrorListener()` also lives in the `LoginActivity` class. Which looks like this:

```
private Response.Listener<String> ReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            try {
                session.setLogin(true);
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                String uid = user.getString("id");
                String name = user.getString("name");
                String email = user.getString("email");

                // Inserting row in users table
                db.addUser(name, email, uid);

                // Launch main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}

private Response.ErrorListener ReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            int  statusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
            Log.d("testerror", "" + statusCode + " " + new String(response.data));
            if (statusCode != 200) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), new String(response.data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

My question is simple how can I refactor this even better? Or did I already refactored it good enough?

Also here is my link to show you how the code looks before and after I had refactored it. Here is the link if you want to see it: https://github.com/superzaky/Kenzup/compare/3b30426bc02873607806525d62d2744921481cd5...command-loginrequest

So on the left side is the code before the refactoring and on the right side is the code after the refactoring.

Comment: What does "better" mean? This seems like a pretty subjective question.

Comment: Well putting somehow the implementation of `ReqSuccessListener()` and `ReqErrorListener()` in the `LoginRequest` or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Great job, you are nearly there. But your code can be 'cleaner'

'Clean code' is not at all subjective, it could be easily defined. Following these will make your code shine  -

- [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))
- Testablity.
- Readability.
- Structuring (cohesion).

Readability is very important, but also a very vast subject, therefore I will not discuss it, but rather encourage you to read about it. Things like [fluent API](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) makes code much more understandable and maintainable. And I recommend Uncle Bob's book [Clean code](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code).

**A few things I learned being an Android developer -**

Android's Activity class by (probably a lack of) design does all kinds and too many things already, unfortunately there is no escape we must inherit from it. But that doesn't mean that one should add more responsibilities to it and make the code more rigid.

Do not be fooled by Android's dev site and many blogs and sites out there. When they purpose a solution, they do not bother themselves with separation of concerns. Naturally they just want to expose the technicalities rather than a 'clean' solution (which is somewhat understandable).

Having a mindset of writing testable code, not necessarily writing tests will make your design much better. Personally I think tests are a must, but I can understand why many Android developers do not write them. The lack of a good and fast testing framework a long side Android framework makes it very inconvenience to have the best of practices. But this should not stop anyone from writing a testable code! Testable code is a better code

**In your code -**

1. Have a clear definition of what you want your Activity class to do.
   A natural thing will be a Controller or Presenter. Once you do, have
   it do that and nothing else. Strive to make it very thin.
2. Have an Abstraction layer over your business rules. It is very likely that some rules will be enforced prior to executing requests. Maybe not so much in login, but as a rule of thumb it makes things more maintainable, testable and extendable. For example you can now 'mock' a login process to test the UI.
3. Have an Abstraction over your transport layers which will be invoked by the business layer exclusively. Again it makes things more maintainable, testable and extendable. For example you can now mock the transport layer to return a predefined response.